# UINAvigationController dealloc problem

Tags: objective-c

I have been struggling with this: One of the viewControllers on myNavigationController allocates values to one of its properties at viewDidLoad {} this property is then used elsewhere. when I pushViewController and then go back to the parent viewcontroller, I get an error at viewdidLoad saying

message sent to deallocated instance 0x3e39810

so the properties have been deallocated.. is there anyway to stop this happening or to reallocate the property I need to set?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to copy over the properties needed to the object using the properties.